# Summing the heights of the views inside my stackview

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uistackview

Hey so Im working on an RSS blog reader component for my app and I’m running into the issue of properly sizing the stack view which is containing the textviews and image views of my parsed blog content. The sizing issue comes from the fact that can’t get the proper heights of those individual textviews and image views.

Please excuse the gaps in my iOS knowledge. I've been teaching myself so sometimes these issues just catch me on a basic level.

I tried doing what a few other stack overflow questions recommended like adding

```
self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
```

but it’s not working.

Here’s a link to the app (just one view controller, <200 SLOC)
https://github.com/stanchiang/ParsingRSS

```
    func feedParser(parser: MWFeedParser, didParseFeedItem item: MWFeedItem) {
        var scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.frame)
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: restructureText(item.summary) as! [UIView])
        stackView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height * 6)
        stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical
        stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistribution.FillProportionally
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.view.setNeedsLayout()

        var fullHeight:CGFloat = 0.0
        for view in stackView.arrangedSubviews {
            if view.isKindOfClass(UITextView) {
                let tv:UITextView = view as! UITextView
                print("textview: \(tv.frame.size)")
            }
            if view.isKindOfClass(UIImageView) {
                let tv:UIImageView = view as! UIImageView
                print("imageview: \(tv.frame.size)")
            }
            fullHeight += view.intrinsicContentSize().height
        }
        print("new:\(fullHeight) vs old:\(stackView.frame.height)")
        scrollView.contentSize = stackView.frame.size

        parser.stopParsing()
    }
```

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? The parsing code seems unimportant, remove that bit. Tell us why you've written the code you have around the stack view. Screenshots help

Comment: the goal is to have the textviews and imageviews in my stackview be optimally sized. for example, the content of the entire textview can be viewed without needing to scroll within the textview itself. the problem is that i failed to find the correct textview height by itself so for now i have resorted to hardcoding the hight of the stack view to be 6 times the height of the "self.view", thereby giving the contained objects enough room to expand fully. but even when i hard code the height of the stack view like that, and they expand to their "right" sizes, printing out the values doesn't work.

Comment: Text views (basically any subclass of scroll view in a way) doesn't have an intrinsic content size

Comment: ok so maybe labels instead of textviews could achieve the same thing without the sizing issue?

Comment: It could, or you calculate and set the text view size

Comment: so i know. i tried calculating the text view size, taking suggestions from existing answers but have been unsuccessful. if you understand what I'm attempting to do, could you explain how i can do it properly?

Comment: What did you try? Set the frame width and check the bounds

Comment: i tried. that was the for loop is at the bottom. but the values are always either 0 or not actually the "correct" height. I tested it by taking the dimensions printed out and adding a uiview on top to compare the dimensions. they weren't even close.